# Editable pdf file is not able to read using pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdf-reader

I have pdf file which  is editable mean when i open the pdf i can select  & change the drop down option in pdf form .
this pdf i am trying to read through pypdf2 module but nothing is coming as output .
Can you guys please let me know how i can read and put the output from editable pdf to json format.
Thanks in advance.As you can see in the screenshot image after opening pdf file we change change the data.
Code which i tried but nothing printsout

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
pdfobject=open("Form11LLP_2019.pdf","rb")
pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
print(pdf.getFormTextFields())
```

i will really appreciate this help.
Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use library `pdfrw`.
But this problem can exist in different viewers or pdf editors.
You can try compare byte code of input file and out if the same.